# Can anyone help me understand one step in the constructing of product measure?

Tags: measure-theory

Given two measure space (X, A, $\mu$), (Y, B, v), let $\{A_k * B_k\}_{k=1}^{k=\infty}$ be a countable disjoint collection of measurable rectangles whose union also is a measurable rectangle A * B.

Why do the following two equalities hold?
$$\mu(A)*v(B)=\int_Xv(B)\chi_Ad\mu$$
$$\Sigma_{k=1}^{k=\infty}\int_Xv(B_k)\chi_{A_k}d\mu = \Sigma_{k=1}^{k=\infty}\mu(A_k)*v(B_k)$$

where $\chi_A$ is a characteristic function.

Comment: $\nu(B)$ is constant, so the first equality is trivial. The second equality is similar. Are you familiar with the fact that $\mu(A)=\int_X \chi_Ad\mu$?

Comment: It looks familiar. I was assuming it is by definition. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I mean, this is measure theory 101. $\chi_A=1$ when $x\in A$ and 0 otherwise.

Comment: I am new to this stuff, but now i get it. $\chi_A$ is a simple function, so it is legesbue integral is just 1 * $\mu(A) = \mu(A)$

Comment: Can you write you post as an answer? I will mark the question as answered.